# php session error when the project is made setup on localhost?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I was going through a `php project`. As the client needs some changes in the design part, I have downloaded all the files and database to my localhost(LAMP). I have imported the database to my phpmyadmin. After that I have made changes to necessary files where the database username and password were mentioned. Now when I browse the site from my browser I got this error

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant session - assumed 'session' in project/session.php
```

After that I just opened the `session.php` file from where the error was coming.The file have the code something like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']="yes"; 
ini_set("url_rewriter.tags","");
ini_set(session.use_trans_sid, false);
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".projectsite.com");
ob_start();
session_start();
$_session_register["esb2b_username"];
$_session_register["esb2b_userid"];
$_session_register["esb2b_memtype"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_id"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_email"];
$_session_register["lang"];
?>
```

I just made commented the line `ini_set(session.use_trans_sid, false);` but still I am getting the error. So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this error? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

**Update**
Now I have made changes my file like this

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']="yes"; 
ini_set("url_rewriter.tags","");
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 0);
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".projectsite.com");
ob_start();
$_session_register["esb2b_username"];
$_session_register["esb2b_userid"];
$_session_register["esb2b_memtype"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_id"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_email"];
$_session_register["lang"];
}
?>
```

and after this my error says like

```
Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in project/session.php on line 6 Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in /project/session.php on line 10 Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in project/session.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in project/session.php on line 12 Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in project/session.php on line 13 Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in project/session.php on line 14 Notice: Undefined variable: _session_register in project/session.php on line 15
```

Comment: remove the second `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

See your second line of `ini_set`. It is missing a quote. and session is started twice

There is no any other bugs that could cause this error. Maybe you need to recheck?

It is advisable to start session as

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {

  session_start();

}
```

FURTHER: Is `$_session_register` an variable? If not, It looks as if it should be `session_register("");`

Answer (score 0):

Just put double quotes around:
`ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", false);`

You don't need to run session twice. only one `session_start();` should be there

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure i try this. you already start session top then why you declared again in middle part.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['example']="yes"; 
ini_set("url_rewriter.tags","");
ini_set($_SESSION['use_trans_sid'], false);
ini_set($_SESSION['cookie_domain'], ".projectsite.com");
ob_start();
$_session_register["esb2b_username"];
$_session_register["esb2b_userid"];
$_session_register["esb2b_memtype"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_id"];
$_session_register["esb2b_adv_email"];
$_session_register["lang"];
```

?>